# Cannot Create Controller with EF Generated DBContext Classes using Partial Classes

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4, dbcontext

I have an interface defined as:

```
public interface ICMDBContext
{
    DBSet<Building> {get;}
    DBSet<Room> {get;}
    more DBSet methods...

    string Save()
 }
```

I have the DBContext generated class named CMDB_DataModelContainer.

I have a partial class CMDB_DataModelContainer which implements ICMDBContext which looks like this (And yes, both are in the same namespace):

```
public partial class CMDB_DataModelContainer : ICMDBContext
{
    string Save() { implemenation... }
}
```

Everything compiles all fine and dandy, but when I try to create a controller and use CMDB_ModelConatiner as the context class (creating a Strongly-typed controller) I get the error

> There was an error generating 'CMDB.Domain.Models.CMDB_DataModelContainer'. Try rebuilding your project.

I removed the partial class and was able to create the controller. Any ideas why this would happen?

To add, the DBContext classes are in a separate project.

The fact it is in a separate project doesn't matter. I created a test project with DBcontext class and the MVC3 app in same project and still a no go.

I suppose a question to ask is if anyone has actually setup a repository when using Model first approach. I am finding myself running into problem after problem trying to apply this pattern when using model first.

If you want to recreate the issue, just make an MVC 3 (or 4, I used 3). This is what I did for a test to recreate it myself.

Add a new ADO.Net Entity Data Model.

- Create two entities: Taco and Filling
- Add a "name" scalar property to each.
- Add association m <---> m
- Create a new folder named "Partial" in the models folder.
- Add a new class - the class should be named the same as the Context class (if you left default names it should be Model1Container) and in the same namespace.

e.g.

```
public partial class Model1Container
{

}
```

- Add a new controller "TacoController" as strongly typed against, you guessed it, Taco, and using the Model1Container as the context class. Voila, reproduced. Yes, I like tacos.

Comment: What the *filename* containing your `CMDB_DataModelContainer : ICMDBContext` ?

Comment: CMDB_Model.cs. I didn't believe filenames mattered in C# as they did in Java.  I tried renaming the file to the DBContext generated file. Still no go.

Comment: Where have you implemented your DbSet property accessors? (the actual code for DbSet<Building> {get...} ) Also you may want to use IDbSet here instead (may make no difference, but it is an abstraction rather than a concrete implementation you are referring to)

Comment: @Adam the property accessors are defined in the T4 generated DbContext class named CMDB_DataModelContainer. I created the partial class CMDB_DataModelContainer to add the interface to setup use of a repository. I found that the interface is not the issue itself, but the use of a partial class with the T4 generated DBContext class. Whether I implement an interface, or not, I still get the error if it is a blank partial class.

Comment: Check out my session here, may help out a bit. Im not using the t4 though, use EF power tools to reverse engineer your context. channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/NorthAmerica/2012/DEV215

Comment: @AdamTuliper Great tips in the session. Unfortunately there isn't a fix to this problem (that is unless I go about not using Model First).

Comment: let me ask you - why are you using model first? you cant push a model to a db, why not just reverse engineer? If you still need an EDMX diagram to look at you can generate one via the power tools. Then you can use code based migrations to sql script your changes, etc

Comment: @AdamTuliper No reason really other than following tutorials. I just started with MVC & EF about 1 month ago so I am not quite familiar with all tools available. I did model first also because I wasn't comfortable enough going code first.

Comment: Try the entity framework power tools. It does it all for you basically : ) Use the method I show in the video to reverse engineer database.

Answer (score 0):

As you have probably discovered, removing(/renaming) the partial class, creating the controller and then reinstating your partial class seems to be an adequate workaround. As for why:

One of the times I tried I noticed something strange: a new declaration had appeared in the partial class file I'd created:

```
public DbSet<Taco> Taco { get; set; }
```

I can only speculate that VS is getting confused by the partial class files - it finds the partial class file you created, doesn't see the DBSet declared, tries to add it and then gets in a tizzy because that's too many tacos.

Chris